# Where is my git folder?

Tags: git

I have a folder on Mac1 (the name of a computer I'll be using) called "git" and in it is an ongoing project that I can 'pull'. This folder is at `MacintoshHD>Users>MyName>git>ProjectName`

I now want to have the same on Mac2 (another computer). This is what I've done so far on Mac2 (with noob skills):

1. Installed git by typing 
   `sudo port install git-core +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb`

   into Terminal after having already installed MacPorts.
2. Did `git config --global user.name "John Doe"` and 
   `git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`, using the same settings as those on Mac1.

Now, I'd like to 'pull' the the latest version of the project folder `ProjectName` onto Mac2. If I was on Mac1, I'd just `cd` to `MacintoshHD>Users>MyName>git>ProjectName` and run `git pull`. However, I don't have this "git" folder in the same directory on Mac2.

What should I do?

Comment: "that I can 'pull'" means there is a remote (master) repository where you pull from?

Comment: what is the output of `git remote -v` on your first repository?

Comment: @User17670 you need to get the address and use it for cloning. `git remote -v` should show at least one remote (usually named `origin`)

Comment: On Mac 1, I get "SomeName@SomeAddress:ProjectName (fetch)" and "SomeName@SomeAddress:ProjectName (push)"

Comment: @User17670 ok that's what you need, check my answer.

Comment: Why are you using `>` rather than `/` to delimit directory names?

Comment: @KeithThompson Habbit I guess. I've only recently started using the command line. Before, I only ever thought about directories when I was looking at them in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push the local repository to some remote host, like GitHub.
Then on any other machine you can get a copy of the repo by using `git clone`

```
git clone SomeName@SomeAddress:ProjectName
```

This will fetch the repository from the remote URL and clone it into your other computer.

To recap

#### On Mac1

```
git push //This will synchronize the local repo with the remote one
```

#### On Mac2

```
mkdir -p /Users/MyName/git // Optional, create a folder named git
cd /Users/MyName/git // Go into that folder
git clone SomeName@SomeAddress:ProjectName // this will create a local copy of the repo
```

You will end up with a git repository inside `/Users/MyName/git/ProjectName`. From now on you can push/pull within it.

Comment: Ok, I implicitly assumed you had a remote host for the git repository.  If you don't, you need to push the repo somewhere (like GitHub) and then clone it on another machine

Comment: The ProjectName folder is on a uni server. I just need to pull it. It's just that I don't know where the folder will go to, since I don't have a "git" folder, like on Mac1 (note: I didn't set up git on Mac1)

Comment: You are messing up a bit. `git pull` will synchronize an existing repo. `git clone` will create a repo cloning a remote one.

Comment: note that `git clone` will create a folder named after the project unless you explicitly specify a name. And it doesn't need at all to be in a folder named `git`. If you want it, just create that folder, but it's really not related to the issue.

Comment: Do I need to push first if I am effectively a 'read only' user?

Comment: If you are are readonly user you cannot push to that remote. The only way you have to synchronize the chances would be to push to a different remote you own, and then clone that one to the second Mac. But I suggest that you read an introduction to git first, since you appear to be very confused about the basics.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. I had git set up for me but not explained well. I only know that I can pull. Maybe I can push, but I was not told about this. BTW, I did read an intro to git (http://git-scm.com/book) but it's pitched at a level that is pretty high to someone who's not used version control. I am trying

Comment: I accepted your answer because I believe it to be decent. I didn't manage to get ProjectName on Mac2 though, because when I did the clone, it asked for a password that I apparently don't know.

Comment: Well, that's another story. If on the first mac it doesn't ask for a password, you are probably authenticating using an ssh key. If that's the case you will need the same keys on the second Mac to authenticate (or knowing the password)

Comment: Yeah, I have an ssh key. I'll ask a question about it, because I want to learn :)